# % Variance change in Matrix SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, variance

Hi I am trying to include Variance in my SSRS matrix for Percentages on a month by month basis.

This is what I want to achieve:

[image: FInal Matrix Result]

the expression I am trying to use which I have got from a forum is as follows:

```
=ReportItems!Textbox15.Value - Code.GetPreviousValue(ReportItems!Textbox15.Value)
```

And this references custom code again from the same forum as follows:

```
Private previousValue As Integer = 0

Public Function GetPreviousValue(ByVal runningValue) As Integer

  Dim temp As Integer = previousValue
  previousValue = runningValue
  Return temp

End Function
```

My issue is this does not work for the variance between April and May for example giving me results that are incorrect.

To be clear April% and May% figures are correct but the variances do not appear as in my example. When I check them they are incorrect.

If I alter the (variance) query so instead of taking the query that calculates the % I just calculate variance between the numerator of April% and numerator of May%, variances are correct.

I think the issue is that percentages don't go through the custom code portion correctly. Could this be due to the fact that this works according to INT?

I appreciate this may be as clear as mud... Struggling a bit to explain my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the integer makes the problem, because you have values with dots (`97.3`, `91.8`, etc...). When these values get converted to integer, they lose the right decimal places. Just replace the datatype in your function like this:

```
Private previousValue As Double = 0

Public Function GetPreviousValue(ByVal runningValue) As Double

  Dim temp As Double = previousValue
  previousValue = runningValue
  Return temp

End Function
```

Comment: Excellent. Dim temp As Integer on third line also changed to Double and worked great.

Comment: Yes you are right I forgot that. I will give it an edit